# How can you see the performance index requirements of a race in Shift 2 Unleashed?

Tags: need-for-speed-shift-2-unleashed

So far the only way I've found is to upgrade your car past the allowed performance index.

Comment: Figured it out, but I can't self-answer for another 7 hours. "When you have the event selected, hit the button for "CHANGE CAR" (Y on Xbox 360, triangle on PS3). The event details are in the lower right of the screen.?

Answer (score 1):

When you have the event selected, hit the button for "CHANGE CAR" (Y on Xbox 360, triangle on PS3). The event details are in the lower right of the screen.